# How do I create a tuple of tuple from a tuple of tuples and ints?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples and integers:

```
[((0, 5), 8), ((0, 1), 10), ((1, 4), -4), ((1, 3), 2), ((1, 2), 1), ((2, 3), -2), ((3, 4), -1), ((4, 5), 1)]
```

How would I go about converting something like that to a list of tuples in format:
[(0, 5, 8), (0, 1, 10), (1, 4, -4),..., (4, 5, 1)]

I've tried

```
edges = tuple(point for i in self.get_edge_list(with_weights=True) for point in i)
```

But it returns just about the same thing. I need to access the values of the tuples

I've tried

```
 edges = tuple(point for i in self.get_edge_list(with_weights=True) for point in i)
```

But it returns just about the same thing. I need to access the values of the tuples

I've also tried

```py
for i in self.get_edge_list(with_weights=True): #get edge list returns the afformentioned list
    edge =[]
    for j in i:
        for t in j:
            edge.append(t)
            edge = tuple(edge)
            edges.append(edge)
```

But I can't iterate over the int in the tuple

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    ((0, 5), 8),
    ((0, 1), 10),
    ((1, 4), -4),
    ((1, 3), 2),
    ((1, 2), 1),
    ((2, 3), -2),
    ((3, 4), -1),
    ((4, 5), 1),
]

out = [(a, b, c) for ((a, b), c) in lst]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    (0, 5, 8),
    (0, 1, 10),
    (1, 4, -4),
    (1, 3, 2),
    (1, 2, 1),
    (2, 3, -2),
    (3, 4, -1),
    (4, 5, 1),
]
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much. I've been struggling with this forever!